# Index creation job failing because of quotation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a job that is part of my staging process and it includes indexing a table post population.

One of the indexes is a filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_IP_ActivePAss] ON [dbo].[IPStg]
(
    [SIP] ASC,
    [EIP] ASC
)
WHERE ([Status] IN ("Active", "Private"))
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The job fails with the following error:

> CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'.  Verify that SET options are correct
>   for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or
>   filtered indexes and/or query notifications  and/or XML data type
>   methods and/or spatial index operations. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error
>   1934).  The step failed.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect to see single quotes not double. I think its a typo.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_IP_ActivePAss] ON [dbo].[IPStg] ( 
    [SIP] ASC, 
    [EIP] ASC 
  ) WHERE ( [Status] IN ('Active', 'Private' )
) WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
         STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
         SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
         DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
         ONLINE = OFF, 
         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
         ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Comment: Its a typo, its a single quote.

Comment: Please mark as answered if you are satisfied that I answered your question correctly

Comment: the problem persists even with a single quote

Comment: The above sql creates a filtered index for me on a sql 2012 box. what version of sql are you running.

Comment: It works if I run it as a query but fails when I stick it into a sql job.